# Por que o atributo download não funciona?

Tags: html5

Estou  tentando acertar um código de link mas não estou tendo o resultado que gostaria, não está funcionando. Como proceder?

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="aaaa"> download </a>
```

Comment: Já viu se é restrição em sua rede?
Pois o exemplo q vc passou funciona corretamente, bom ao menos aqui rs

Comment: Verifique se o navegador que vc está testando tem suporte a HTML5

Answer (score 4):

- No *Google Chrome* ele funciona normalmente
- No *Firefox* é necessário que o arquivo em `href` seja da mesma origem que a página que esta chamando.
- Não é suportado por nenhuma versão do *Internet Explorer* (nem mesmo o 11), no entanto é suportado pelo *Microsoft Edge* versão 13 ou superior.
- Não é suportado pelo *Safari* ou *iOS*

Detalhes em: http://caniuse.com/#search=download%20attribute

### Alternativa

Se usar uma linguagem back-end é possível criar um "webproxy" pra baixar arquivos externos, como por exemplo com PHP (informe se usa alguma outra linguagem no back-end que tentarei fornecer um exemplo):

proxy.php:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

if (empty($_GET['url']) || preg_match('#^(http|https)://[a-z0-9]#i', $_GET['url']) === 0) {
    echo 'URL inválida';
    exit;
}

$url = $_GET['url'];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$nome = basename($url);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $nome . '"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');

echo $data;
```

E o link assim:

```
<a href="proxy.php?url=http://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg">download</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela força,  estou usando vb.net com MVC

Comment: @FabioMoskFabinho MVC quer dizer asp.net-mvc? Qual versão?

Comment: @FabioMoskFabinho qual versão do asp.net-mvc?

Answer (score 3):

Creio que seja incompatibilidade do seu navegador, como mencionado pelo @Guilherme, um simples javascript pode mostrar se seu navegador possui suporte a esse atributo.

```js
alert(("download" in document.createElement("a") ? "Possui suporte." : "Não há suporte."));
```

Comment: Fiz isso e veio o alert como tem suport no caso do Chrome,  valeu pela força